# Selection sort vs. Bubble sort C++

Tags: c++

I made this program to sort a list of numbers. It is supposed to be selection sort, but my teacher said it works more like bubble sort and I need to fix it. Any suggestions on what parts I need to change?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArr(const int a[], int s);
void swapVals(int& v1, int& v2);
void sortArr(int a[], int s);

int main()
{
    const int s = 20;
    int arr[s] = {8, 38, 25, 4, 47, 47, 38, 36, 3, 33, 2, 19, 16, 30, 5, 47, 16,
                  38, 13, 1
                 };

    cout << "Unsorted array:\n";
    printArr(arr, s);
    cout << "\n\n";

    sortArr(arr, s);

    cout << "Sorted Array:\n";
    printArr(arr, s);
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}

void sortArr(int a[], int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s-1; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s; j++)
            if (a[j] < a[index])
                index = j;
        swapVals(a[index], a[i]);
    }
}

void swapVals(int& v1, int& v2)
{
    int temp = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = temp;
}

void printArr(const int a[], int s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
        if (i != s-1)
            cout << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the algorithm code example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort  - there is a test for `iMin != j`  (`index != i` in your implementation) - otherwise it appears to be the same.  When presenting code for others to help with it pays not to include superfluous unused code such as `FindMIn()`.  Perhaps your teacher is confused by your inconsistent indentation - fixed that for you (and removed `findMin()`  - its just a distraction).

Comment: Format it clearly, add some comments to indicate that you understand it rather then just copied it from the web, perhaps add a check to avoid swapping a value with itself and resubmit it - it is selection sort implementation, but it is perhaps not clear.  I'd also recommend using braces around even single statement code blocks - it is much clearer - especially if your indentation is as inconsistent as yours was.

Comment: Here this might help a little [link](http://www.cs.csubak.edu/~msarr/visualizations/ComparisonSort.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's selection sort, just the way you write the code makes it easy for people to misunderstand.

For which part to change, I'll have to say, it's inside your sortArr function, the inner loop, better to add a comment here "find the index of min starting from i + 1" or you can just call the findMin you have defined. From the call routine: main call sortArr, sortArr only call swap and does not call findMin, it looks really like a bubble sort.

Also, your findMin is not good, it's finding min value, not the index of min value.

Comment: My apologies - I removed the unused `findMin()` in the original question - I did not know you were going to reference it in the answer.  It is in any case superfluous, when `swapVals()` is called, `index` is an index to the minimum value.  Looks _almost_ identical to the example code on Wikipedia with different variable names and no check for swapping a value with itself.

Comment: As I said, I believe it's selection sort, just not clear to your teacher, which may cause your problem. This may not be really a programming problem.

Comment: Note that it is not my question; it _was_ just my edit.  The lesson perhaps is not to give your teacher a hard time by submitting badly formatted comment free code.